# Fingerprint sensor on Thinkpad L13 Yoga with Kubuntu 22.04

Tags: kubuntu, kde, fingerprint-reader

I wanted to use the fingerprint sensor with said setup but I can't seem to get it to work.
When I run `fprintd-enroll` I get the following message:
`Impossible to enroll: GDBus.Error:net.reactivated.Fprint.Error.NoSuchDevice: No devices available`

My exact laptop model is [this](https://psref.lenovo.com/Detail/ThinkPad_L13_Yoga?M=20R5000AGE)

`lsusb` output:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 056a:51f6 Wacom Co., Ltd Pen and multitouch sensor
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00be Synaptics, Inc.
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:9540 Alcor Micro Corp. AU9540 Smartcard Reader
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b681 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd ThinkPad T490 Webcam
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0aaa Intel Corp. Bluetooth 9460/9560 Jefferson Peak (JfP)
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`lspci` output:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake-U v1 4c Host Bridge/DRAM Controller (rev 0c)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation CometLake-U GT2 [UHD Graphics] (rev 02)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 0c)
00:08.0 System peripheral: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/v6 / E3-1500 v5 / 6th/7th/8th Gen Core Processor Gaussian Mixture Model
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Thermal Subsytem
00:13.0 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Integrated Sensor Solution
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP Shared SRAM
00:14.3 Network controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP CNVi WiFi
00:15.0 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Serial IO I2C Host Controller
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake Management Engine Interface
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCI Express Root Port #13 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP LPC Premium Controller/eSPI Controller
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Comet Lake PCH-LP SMBus Host Controller
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller: Intel Corporation Comet Lake SPI (flash) Controller
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (10) I219-V
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS522A PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work? Seems like the device is

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:00be Synaptics, Inc.
```

Comment: I don't see your fingerprint sensor ID (06cb:00be) in the [list of supported devices](https://fprint.freedesktop.org/supported-devices.html) by fprint.

Comment: @JosepM.Ferrer Does that mean, it's not possible to use it under Linux at all?

Comment: Is there a way to request that feature at the project? I couldn't find a way to open an issue on their GitLab page...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of 17. March 2024 there is no support for this type of fingerprint reader (`06cb:00be`) as it is already listed in the [unsupported devices](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/libfprint/wiki/-/wikis/Unsupported%20Devices) of the `libfprint` GitLab page.

So unfortunately that means waiting until the developers get it to work.